# How to pass variables into MySql Procedure creation

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to be able to create some stored Procedures in different databases - so I want to be able to pass in the database name into the stored procedure creation statement.

```
SET @SourceDBName='dev';
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN 
    USE @SourceDBName;
    SELECT * FROM agreed_relation;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

How can I pass `@SourceDBName` into the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

Answer (score 2):

to pass in the database name into a stored procedure you must declare it in the procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN idbname VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN 
    SELECT * FROM agreed_relation WHERE dbname = idbname;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

After you create a Table like this where 'dbname' field it's the one your procedure will call:

```
create table agreed_relation
(
dbname varchar(30) not null
);
```

After insert some values you call the procedure and pass any dbname to the SELECT statament:

```
insert into agreed_relation(dbname) values('Oracle');
insert into agreed_relation(dbname) values('Mysql');
insert into agreed_relation(dbname) values('Mongodb');
```

Calling procedure and passing some value:

```
CALL test('Mysql');
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorant question - but it appears you are moving all the tables from the different db into one table, correct?   I was looking for a generic way to pass a variable when I create several different tables in different databases.

Comment: You can't just pass one variable into diferente databases, you must stay or "use" one db at the time, and call the procedures inside the db, just try calling one procedure,remember use "CREATE PROCEDURE test (IN idbname VARCHAR(20))" to pass variables when you call it "CALL test('value');" "idbname" it's the variable declared inside the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

> [14.1.16 CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html)
>
> ...
>
> [USE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html) statements within stored routines are not permitted. When a
>   routine is invoked, an implicit USE db_name is performed (and undone
>   when the routine terminates). The causes the routine to have the given
>   default database while it executes. References to objects in databases
>   other than the routine default database should be qualified with the
>   appropriate database name.
>
> ...

An option to create the stored procedure in different databases is:

FIle: `/path/to/file/myProcedure.sql`

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM `agreed_relation`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> USE `dev`;
Database changed

mysql> \. /path/to/file/myProcedure.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `db1`;
Database changed

mysql> \. /path/to/file/myProcedure.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `db2`;
Database changed

mysql> \. /path/to/file/myProcedure.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `dev`;
Database changed

mysql> CALL `test`;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE `db1`;
Database changed

mysql> CALL `test`;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE `db2`;
Database changed

mysql> CALL `test`;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

You can also create the stored procedure in a single database and pass the database name as a parameter to qualified the required objects and use [14.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to execute it:

```
mysql> USE `dev`;
Database changed

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `test`(`db_name` VARCHAR(64))
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET `db_name` := TRIM('\'' FROM QUOTE(`db_name`));
    ->   SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `', `db_name`, '`.`agreed_relation`');
    ->   PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    ->   EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->   DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `test`('dev');
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CALL `test`('db1');
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CALL `test`('db2');
Empty set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```